# How do I fix it when is says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'type'?

Tags: python, replit

I know there is something wrong, with this, something about the types, but I forgot how to change it.

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if number/2 == int + float:
  print("This number is an odd number")
else:
  print("This number is an even number")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't use datatype as operands. Use any variable(s) instead.
Let me do this for you

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if number % 2 != 0:
  print("This number is an odd number")
else:
  print("This number is an even number")
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says "can't operate + on 'types' and 'types' , you can't use int+float together coz practically that doesn't make sense. And when you are comparing you need to compare it with fixed no. and int doesn't define any fix number. Try comparing reminder with zero since any even no. divided by 2 will give no reminder.

Something like this:

```
if number%2 == 0:
  print("This number is an even number")
else:
  print("This number is an odd number")
```

Answer (score -1):

The statement type & type is trying to compare is if integer + float are equal to var(number) / 2 is false by nature instead you should do var1 + var2 when comparing.

Answer:

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if (number % 2) > 0:
  print("This number is an odd number")
else:
  print("This number is an even number")
```

How to approach equals example:

```html
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if number == 1+2:
  print("This is correct")
else:
  pass
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it, It now changes to

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))
if number / 2 == 0:
  print("This number is an even number")
else:
  print("This number is an odd number")
```